# Create / drop table in postgres using InstantSql in rmcobol

Tags: postgresql, cobol

Using the document below, I was able to perform select/update/insert using rm/cobol to Postgres Database in Linux.

https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/rm-cobol/1214/ISQLhelp/InstantSQLTableOfContents.htm

However, I am unable to create a table or drop a table using InstantSql. Below are the errors I see. I am unable to see any sample in the document above.

## drop table

### prepare query

```
MOVE "drop table persons1"
  TO sql-QrySQL

SQL PREPARE QUERY sql-QueryHandle,
    sql-ConnectionHandle,
    sql-QrySQL.

IF NOT sql-OK
  display "UNSUCCESFUL PREPARE!!!"
  PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL sql-EndOfData
    SQL DESCRIBE ERROR
    sql-Error-Description
    IF NOT sql-EndOfData
      PERFORM DISPLAY-ERROR-INFO
    END-IF
  END-PERFORM
  GO TO Z
END-IF
```

### start query

```
SQL START QUERY sql-QueryHandle.
IF NOT sql-OK
  display "UNSUCCESFUL START!!!"
  PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL sql-EndOfData
    SQL DESCRIBE ERROR
    sql-Error-Description
    IF NOT sql-EndOfData
      PERFORM DISPLAY-ERROR-INFO
    END-IF
  END-PERFORM
  GO TO Z
END-IF
```

Compilation success.

### execution result

```
UNSUCCESFUL START!!!
Err Msg ERROR: syntax error at or near "drop" at character 29;
Error while executing the query

Err TypO
Err statement SQLExecute
ErrsqlSate HY000
err no {00007
```

## table creation

### prepare query

```
MOVE "CREATE TABLE Persn2(PersonID int)"
  TO sql-QrySQL

SQL PREPARE QUERY sql-QueryHandle,
    sql-ConnectionHandle,
    sql-QrySQL.
```

### execution

```
UNSUCCESFUL START!!!
Err Msg ERROR: syntax error at or near "create" at character 28;
Error while executing the query

Err TypO
Err statement SQLExecute
ErrsqlSate HY000
err no {00007
```

## other options

However I am able to do these directly to my postgres database in Linux.

I have tried grant statement as well but the grant also shows the same error as above.
(I have tried to give the statement without quotes, with single, double quotes as well)

```
 Move "grant create on database ttrac to 'postgres';"
                  to sql-QrySQL


           SQL PREPARE QUERY sql-QueryHandle,
               sql-ConnectionHandle,
               sql-QrySQL.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `MOVE`statement. I think so.
Try something like this for all `MOVE` Statements

```
MOVE 'DROP TABLE "persons1"' TO sql-QrySQL
```

I have just added `'` to the `SQL`

Please do revert, if this was the issue or not